# Fast lookup in list of intervals

Tags: python

I have a list of start-end positions with ~280.000 elements. Totally covering about 73.000.000 positions.

For performance reasons I already split them into parts in a dictionary (by a subsetting factor), which in turn contains a list of tuples (start,end).

Finally I get a list of positions, which I want to test if they are located in the regions spanned by start and end.

```
posit = (start,end)
dict[subset].append(posit)

for position in dict[subset]:
    if posit[0] < varpos < posit[1]:
    # do some stuff here
```

Currently those look ups take a long time. But due to memory considerations I also don't want to produce a faster set containing all positions between start and stop.

Do you have any pointers how to create a fast start,end position data structure or a better look up strategy?

Comment: Look into [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) and [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). This is a special case of the so called [stabbing problem](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/ds/ds10/tutorial/tutorial6.pdf)

Comment: what about python bisect ? it can fecth you faster

Comment: Why not append all (start, end) tuples and then sort the resulting list?  Then iterate over the sorted list to determine overlaps (they will be next to each other).  Or are you too memory constrained for this approach?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to tree approaches. I'll look into them.
@StevenRumbalski: The list is sorted, but still running through takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

My assumptions are that the ranges do not overlap and the 280000 range objects are not changing on a regular basis. My first instinct is to use sorted list of lists instead of a list of dictionary objects. Then I would import the list of positions and pass them into a 'findRange' method.

To test my implementation I generated a sorted list of 280000 lists. Then passed 1000 random 'possiblePositionMatches' into findRange for matching.

This implementation took 7.260579 seconds for 100 'possiblePositionMatches' and 71.96268 seconds for 1000 'possiblePositionMatches'.

```
import random
import time

values = list()
for a in range(0,73000000,250) :
    values.append([a, a+200])

possiblePositionMatches = list()
count = 1000
while count:
    count = count - 1
    possiblePositionMatches.append(random.randint(0,73000000))

matches = []

def findRange(value) :
    for x in range(len(values)) :
        if (value >= values[x][0]) and (value < values[x][1]) :
            matches.append([value, values[x]])

def main():
    t1 = time.process_time()
    for y in possiblePositionMatches: 
        findRange(y)
    print (matches)
    t2 = time.process_time() - t1
    print("Total Time: {0} seconds".format(t2))

main()
```